# How to execute C code through PHP by prompting terminal

Tags: php

I have a C code that I have to execute through PHP,
I have used `exec('./sys')`, `sys` is my executable file.
I have also tried `system()`, `passthrough()`, `shell_exec()` and they are not giving output.

When I executed  `exec('who');` it gives the output.

What can I do to execute `sys`?

Comment: try `exec('ls')` or `exec('pwd')` to see where you are, and make sure `sys` is actually there

Answer (score 1):

Each of those methods you reference will execute your `sys` file, but you need to make sure you are executing the correct path. Your working path is determined by what script is actually executing PHP. For example, if you're executing your code through apache or the command line your working directory may be different. Lets assume this file structure:

```
+ src/
| + script.php
| + sys
```

I would recommend using PHP's `__DIR__` magic variable in your script.php to always reference the current file's directory, and then work from there:

```
// script.php
exec(__DIR__ . "/sys");
```

Retrieving output can be done a couple different ways. If you want to store the output of the script in a variable, I would recommend using `exec` according the the manual:

> **Parameters** ¶
>
> **command**
> The command that will be executed.
>
> **output**
> If the output argument is present, then the specified array will be filled with every line of output from the command. Trailing whitespace, such as \n, is not included in this array. Note that if the array already contains some elements, exec() will append to the end of the array. If you do not want the function to append elements, call unset() on the array before passing it to exec().
>
> **return_var**
> If the return_var argument is present along with the output argument, then the return status of the executed command will be written to this variable.

`exec` will return the first line of output, but if you want more than that you need to pass a variable by reference:

```
// script.php
$output = array();
exec(__DIR__ . "/sys", $output);
```

`$output` will then contain an array of each line of output from the command. However if you want to run your `sys` script and directly pass through the output then use `passthru(__DIR__ . "/sys");` For example, if you wanted to execute a command that required input on the command line, `passthru` would be the best option.

Comment: I tried  $output = array();
exec(__DIR__ . "/sys", $output); but out put is "array()"..i exicuted exec("ls",$output);, it gives me correct results......My c program contain a code for creating users for ubuntu system and generating public key for them.

Comment: .Cant i prompt the terminal when i exicuting php?

Comment: if i exicute   exec("mkdir hi",$output);  directory not creating...output is'' Array()''

Comment: are you trying to echo `$output` directly? You cannot do that in PHP. Try `print_r($output);`